# Structure program stops without any error

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, stack

This is a simple program to implement stack using structure pointers. However on running the code my program exits without showing any error.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define maxsize 5

struct s
{
    char array[maxsize];
    int top;
};
typedef struct s stack;


int insert(stack *p)
{
    char ch;
    /*if(p->top==NULL)
      {
      p->top=-1;
      }*/
    if(p->top>=maxsize-1)
    {
        printf("Stack overflows on insertion\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Enter the character to be inserted : ");
        scanf("\n%c",&ch);
        p->top++;
        p->array[p->top]=ch;
    }
}
int delete(stack *p)
{
    if(p->top==-1)
    {
        printf("Stack underflows on deletion\n");
    }
    else
    {
        p->top--;
    }
}
int display(stack *p)
{
    int i;
    if(p->top==-1)
    {
        printf("Stack is empty\n");
    }
    else
    {
        for(i=0;i<=p->top;i++)
        {
            printf("%c",p->array[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main()
{
    int c;
    stack *p;
    p->top=-1;
    while(1)
    {
        printf("1--> INSERT  2--> DELETE  3--> DISPLAY\n");
        scanf("%d",&c);
        switch(c)
        {
            case 1:
                insert(p);
                break;
            case 2:
                delete(p);
                break;
            case 3:
                display(p);
                break;
            default:
                printf("ERROR : Invalid Choice");
        }
    }
}
```

This program contains three functions to push, pop and display the elements in the stack, and the last main function is from where the function call is executed.

The program gets compiled successfully with 0 errors, but while running it exits without displaying anything.

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow. Did you try debugging? Also what exactly is the flow that produces the error?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: Please address your warnings first.  In main() p is used before set (p->top = -1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you declare:

```
  stack *p;
```

It is just declaring a pointer.  You need to allocate memory if you want to use the pointer - as you do here (this will segfault):

```
   p->top=-1;
```

Update the first line to the following:

```
   stack *p = malloc(sizeof(stack));
```

malloc() will allocate the requested memory for use - anything dynamically allocated should also be free()'d